# Подключение ethernet, Linux

Tags: linux, dhcp, ethernet

Есть машина с материнкой ASROCK N68-GS4 FX. Не хочет подключаться к роутеру по кабелю.

```
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s7 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval XX
```

Несколько раз повторяется в syslog, а после выдаёт сообщение о таймауте запроса.

lspci | grep Ethernet:

```
Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)
```

В винде на той же машине всё работает, загружался в лайве со многих дистров (дебиан, минт, манджаро), нигде не работает. Спасибо заранее

Comment: Видел подобное на каких-то асусах, у которых после обновления биоса уехал MAC на контроллере. Кстати, приведённый вывод `lspci` мне тоже не кажется адекватным — обычно или bridge (PCI, ISA), либо ethernet controller. Да и по умолчанию там должен быть номер шины в левой колонке.

Comment: Вот вывод с манджаро:  00:07.0 Bridge [0680]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet [10de:03ef] (rev a2)

Answer (score 1):

Гуглёж даёт некоторое количество похожих проблем. Есть вероятность, что почти все они возникают из-за кривого DHCP-сервера, который плохо отвечает на линуксовые DHCP-запросы (и, в частности, положительно реагирует на установку `send dhcp-client-identifier = hardware;` в dhclient.conf)

Варианты:

1. Поменять DHCP-сервер (ну или просто убедиться, что оно работает так же/по-другому с другим DHCP-сервером).
2. Вынести NetworkManager и настроить сеть через /etc/network/interfaces (в дебианопроизводных) и dhcp-клиент, обратив внимание на настройку `dhcp-client-identifier`

Не забудьте перед началом убедиться, что у вас вообще лампочка соединения на ethernet-интерфейсе загорается, а то, как обычно, потом выяснится, что контакта нет...